# Sitecore CLI Error executing dotnet sitecore ser pull

Tags: serialization, sitecore-cli

I am currently following the Sitecore CLI Documentation and testing it out on one of my local sitecore environment.

I am executing the command

```
dotnet sitecore ser pull
```

and I am getting this error.

```
You are not authorized to perform the task you are attempting. You may need to be assigned additional permissions.
```

Anyone know how to resolve this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this is recommended to update the settings on the config `Sitecore.Services.GraphQL.Serialization.config` but it does resolve my issue by updating the `requireAuthentication` node to false (Default: true).

```
<security type="Sitecore.Services.GraphQL.Hosting.Security.GraphQLSecurity, Sitecore.Services.GraphQL">
          <requireAuthentication>false</requireAuthentication>
          <requireApiKey>false</requireApiKey>
        </security>
```

I am now able to pull the items that I want to serialize.

Comment: Indeed it's not recommended as anyone could call the endpoint and change data

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Admin or some other account to log in (sitecore login --cm ... --authority https://..., is someone else in your group also using Sitecore CLI?  do you have a .sitecore directory?  If so then there is a user.json file in there, which contains the token.  Try deleting that file and logging in again.  The user.json should not be checked in to source control.

Comment: I am only using a local environment and only use administrator user. I have already tried deleting the file and logging in again but still the same.

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into the same error.

I remembered disabling OWIN in the site settings by `Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Disabler.config`.

I solved it when I enabled OWIN.

Answer (score 0):

The first step is to check if a user is created within Sitecore.

When the The Sitecore CLI user is created without an emailaddress, which causes the exception.

Second Check SQL Membership provider in your `web.config`.

This error only occurs when you have set `requiresUniqueEmail` to `true`

```
<membership defaultProvider="sitecore" hashAlgorithmType="SHA1">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="sitecore" type="Sitecore.Security.SitecoreMembershipProvider, Sitecore.Kernel" realProviderName="sql" providerWildcard="%" raiseEvents="true" />
    <add name="sql" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="security" applicationName="sitecore" minRequiredPasswordLength="1" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="true" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" />
    <add name="disabled" type="Sitecore.Security.DisabledMembersipProvider, Sitecore.Kernel" applicationName="sitecore" />
    <add name="switcher" type="Sitecore.Security.SwitchingMembershipProvider, Sitecore.Kernel" applicationName="sitecore" mappings="switchingProviders/membership" />
  </providers>
</membership>
```

Make it False and Save the config.
Hope this helps, Nikhil!